# Error Making POST to ServiceM8

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I'm getting the following error making a POST request to ServiceM8:

`{'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Length': '343', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Date': 'Wed, 04 Jan 2017 16:57:31 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-Cache': 'Error from cloudfront', 'Via': '1.1 49ccc390fa499ab821b632cf67d38720.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)', 'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'DCkbBH5hfQ-ZyeyefPZJAyaVhKar_oD3n_VDZ8TYS97CyLpG4r5YGQ=='}`

I'm currently using:
`Django==1.10.4`
`requests==2.12.4`

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to pass the company id as `company_uuid`. I changed it to just `company_id`, and it worked perfectly.